# How to make Agents not exceed token length in Langchain?

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, chatgpt-api

I am currently trying to make use of a ChatGPT plugin in langchain:

```
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.agents import load_tools, initialize_agent
from langchain.agents import AgentType
from langchain.tools import AIPluginTool

tool = AIPluginTool.from_plugin_url("https://www.wolframalpha.com/.well-known/ai-plugin.json")

llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, streaming=True, max_tokens=1000)
tools = load_tools(["requests_all"])
tools += [tool]

agent_chain = initialize_agent(
    tools, llm, agent=AgentType.ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION, verbose=True
)
# agent_chain.run("what t shirts are available in klarna?")

agent_chain.run("How can I solve dx/dt = a(t)*x + b(t)")
```

However, I get the error:

```
InvalidRequestError: This model's maximum context length is 4097 tokens. However, you requested 5071 tokens (4071 in the messages, 1000 in the completion). Please reduce the length of the messages or completion.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the wolframalpha prompt is as large as the base gpt-3.5's allowed context window.

One thing you can do is use the 16k token context model.

`llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, streaming=True, max_tokens=1000, model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo-16k")`

Hopefully this helps you.

Comment: Hi @netr, many thanks for your input. The only problem I see, is that the 16k model is more expensive. Hence, is there a way around?

Comment: Hi @netr, I now tried this and I got the following error: `ValueError: An output parsing error occurred. In order to pass this error back to the agent and have it try again, pass `handle_parsing_errors=True` to the AgentExecutor. This is the error: Could not parse LLM output: `I now know the final answer.`
`

Comment: It looks like the langchain parsing is not working properly. `I now know the final answer` is usually given by the LLM in that prompt when it has done it's reasoning steps. 

Try removing:

`tools = load_tools(["requests_all"])` -- it might be trying to do something with that tool.

Comment: @tobias I also had the same issue with `create_csv_agent`. I solved it by removing a space after the colon `:` of each step's description (ex : `Question: the input question you must answer` -> `Question:the input question you must answer`) in the prompt template of the agent.